# How to calculate the transfer rate of data by sending ping reques or http request in c#?

Tags: c#, networking

I want to calculate the transfer rate of data with a remote client or server using c# and show the transfer rates (byte/second) in a chart. here is my code (sorry if the formatting of my code is not correct):

```
                IPAddress address;
                if (IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out address))
                {
                    var reply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(ipAddress, timeout, 
                                                                       buffer, options);
                    ? ((double)buffer?.Length / reply?.RoundtripTime * 
                                                 1000).Value.ToString("N2") : "-1";
                    if (reply?.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        return ((double)buffer?.Length / ((double)reply?.RoundtripTime / 
                                                                  1000)).ToString("N2");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "-1";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (HttpClient httpClient = new())
                        {

                            var sw = new Stopwatch();
                            sw.Start();

                            using (HttpClient httpClient = new())
                        {

                            var sw = new Stopwatch();
                            sw.Start();
                            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"http://{ipAddress}"
                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                var content = response.Content;
                                var size = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                sw.Stop();

                                return (size.Length / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("N2");
                                
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return "-1";
                            }
                        }
                       
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                }
```

I do not want to use ping for URLs that are not IP address. but the transfer rate is very different in these two methods. when using http request the  `size.Length` is something like 50000 and the transfer rate would be 20000. when using ping the transfer rate would be like 400. Is there a better way to calculate the transfer rate for bytes/second for both scenarios and also in case which the ping is not allowed in remote client or server?

Comment: You can calculate the _current_ transfer rate by actually transferring something. A couple of pings will not say anything about the transfer rate.